# ToolTipText on Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tooltip

How to create a tool tip text in a specific column on JTable.

This is what I have come up to.

```
itemTable = new JTable(model){
            if (c instanceof JComponent) {
                if(columns == 7){
                    JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;
                    jc.setToolTipText("Price per item");
                }
            }
            return c;
        }
    };
```

Sad to say this is not working.

Comment: This is an anonymous class, but you write code directly in the class body instead of inside a method. What was supposed to be the logic of this? What is `c`, what is `columns`?

Answer (score 3):

Usually the tool tip would be added to the header of the table.

One way to do this is to override the `getToolTipText(...)` method of the `JTableHeader`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Specifying Tool Tips for Table Headers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#headertooltip) for a working example.

The same concept can be applied for the JTable as well.

The tutorial also shows how you could use a custom renderer to set the tool tip text.